# Converting a table to a raster for clipping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, tab, files

I have a series of tables (TAB files) that represent the calculated values for a corresponding .tif image.  These tab files have the same number of rows and columns as pixels in the tif images.  The tif files are georeferenced and correspond to a study area I am using and I want to be able to extract the tab info for only the values within the study area.  Anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Or if I can just relate the table to the tif so each column and row is related to the corresponding pixel of each column/row in the tif.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: Or if I can just relate the table to the tif so each column and row is related to the corresponding pixel of each column/row in the tif

Comment: the software I am using is ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: Please be aware that there is an edit button beneath your question that enables you to revise it at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I would (providing the TAB and tif files have *exactly* the same cells):

1. extract the centre of each tif pixel as an xy coordinate
2. write the xy file to csv (1. & 2. can be done together with gdal)
3. read the xy file and TAB files into a program (R/python/whatever)
4. stack the TAB file columns
5. join/merge/rowbind the xy and TAB files and export to xyz
6. read the xyz file into the GIS of your choice and make a raster

Finally, make sure you don't get data in that format again - it sounds like a total chore and a recipe for errors!